# HTML & CSS with div problems

Tags: html, css

I am beginner in CSS & HTML and still learning on it.

I want to get this result:

[image]

can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.process {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    height: 255px;
    width: 630px;
}

.process img {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 33px;
}

.lockup {
    text-align: center;
}

.lockup h2 {
    color: #5db442;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sign {
    
}

.fill {
   
    
}

.fill p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="process">
                
                <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/m5kmwz9ov/upanddown.png"/>
                
                <div class="lockup">
                
                    <div class="sign">
                    <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/h2h988fdb/signup.png" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="fill">
                        <h2>Signup Process</h2>

                    <p>1. User enters email address</p>
                      <p> 2. Clicks on "Sign up for free"</p>  
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
```

please help thanks.

Comment: What you have tried, Where is your CSS for this?

Comment: @Ryan Even If you are a beginner, It doesn't mean that you shouldn't try to solve it by yourself rather than posting on SO to give you solution.

Comment: muhammad i already tried it more than 10 times still can't get the solution that's why i posted this already.

Comment: @RyanRiel Please post jsFiddle or Codepen so ppl can help you.

Comment: here ty for your suggestion https://jsfiddle.net/hmxbes8u/

Answer (score 1):

Please have look at following jsFiddle, I hope it works for you.
[jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/hmxbes8u/1/)

```
<div class="process"> <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/m5kmwz9ov/upanddown.png"/>
  <div class="lockup">
    <div class="sign"> <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/h2h988fdb/signup.png" /> </div>
    <div class="fill">
      <h2>Signup Process</h2>
      <p>1. User enters email address</p>
      <p> 2. Clicks on "Sign up for free"</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
body {
    background: black;
}
.process {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    height: 255px;
    width: 630px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.process img {
    /*text-align: center;
    display: block;*/
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 33px;
}
.lockup {
    text-align: center;
}
.lockup h2 {
    color: #5db442;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sign {
    float: left;
    width: 43%;
    text-align: right;
}
.fill {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 4%;
}
.fill p {
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: yay thanks. but i have a question why the use percentage in width and padding?

Comment: Percentage will help in case you want to make it responsive at some point after that you can set media query to handle that.

Same you can do by giving PX to but I do that way. :)

Everyone has there own style of working/Coding.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Look below code or Here is jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/hmxbes8u/2/

I hope this will help you.

HTML

```
<div class="process">

                <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/m5kmwz9ov/upanddown.png"/>

                <div class="lockup">

                    <div class="sign">
                    <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/h2h988fdb/signup.png" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="fill">
                        <h2>Signup Process</h2>

                    <p>1. User enters email address</p>
                      <p> 2. Clicks on "Sign up for free"</p>  
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: black;
}

.process {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    height: 255px;
    width: 630px;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.process > img {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 33px;
}

.lockup {
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    right:0;
    left:0;

}

.lockup h2 {
    color: #5db442;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top:0;
}

.sign {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:30px;
}

.fill {
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:left;

}

.fill p {
  color: white;
}
```